# Laravel model's value not changed

Tags: laravel

How to change the eloquent object's value? Does it need to be saved?

```
//$order_product_option = $order->order_products->order_product_option;

foreach($orders as $order){
    foreach($order->order_products as $order_product){
        foreach($order_product->order_product_options as $order_product_option){
            echo $order_product_option->quantity; // 10
            $order_product_option->quantity = 20;
            echo $order_product_option->quantity; // still 10 !
            
            $some_array['quantity'] = $order_product_option->quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it always the original value?

Comment: try add link (&) for each elem of foreach

Comment: $order_product_option->quantity = 20;  $order_product_option->save();

Comment: you're supposed to ->save() and ->refresh() model to see changes. referece: [Laravel Docs - Refreshing Models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#refreshing-models) && [Laravel Docs - Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#updates)

Comment: Do you have an attribute accessor? It will override your value.
This will either be [`getQuantityAttribute()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) or [`quantity(): Attribute`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) depending on what version you are using.